# Moving joomla installed directory?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm developing a site in Joomla! 1.5 on my currently active server.  I installed joomla in a folder at the root of my server, so I access it at http://www.whatever.com/folder while I'm developing.  Once it's ready for roll out, how do I move the installation to the root of the directory?  Is it as simple as moving the files, or do I need to change some configuration within joomla, too?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is move the files to the root, nothing else changes with the possible exception of one line in HTACCESS is you have SEF URLs turned on already.

You should also seriously consider building your site on 1.7. You are going to be at end of life for 1.5 next April, you might as well start on the new version to make updating easier.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change these lines in the configuration.php file:

```
var $log_path = 'absolutepathtoyoursite\foldername\logs'; //remove foldername from path
var $tmp_path = 'absolutepathtoyoursite\foldername\tmp';  //remove foldername from path
var $live_site = 'http://www.yoursite.com/foldername'; // remove the foldername or leave empty
```

Might also work without changing these values. I always change them though.